# Why are Styled Component props displaying as HTML attributes?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm passing down boolean props to Styled Components to change styling based on the props that are passed into the Component, like so:

```
    <Button href="#contact" small elevate={false} display="primary">
      CONTACT
    </Button>
```

The output of this JSX is invalid HTML that looks like this:

```
    <a href="#contact" class="Button__ButtonWrapper-fvVzGy gOcROU" display="primary" fluid="0" elevate="0" small="1">
      CONTACT
    </a>
```

Any idea how to ensure props won't be displayed as HTML attrs?

Full Button component:

```
    const ButtonWrapper = styled.button`

    padding: ${props =>
    props.small
      ? `${rem(6)} ${props.theme.sizes.sm}`
      : `${rem(12)} ${props.theme.sizes.med}`};

    box-shadow: ${props =>
      props.elevate
        ? `0 10px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10)`
        : `0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10)`};
    color: ${props => {
      if (props.display === 'primary') return  props.theme.buttons.primary.color;
      if (props.display === 'secondary')
      return props.theme.buttons.secondary.color;
    }};

    `;


    const Button = ({
     display,
     fluid,
     children,
     cta,
     elevate,
     small,
     ...other
    }) => {

    <ButtonWrapper
      display={display}
      fluid={fluid ? 1 : 0}
      elevate={elevate ? 1 : 0}
      small={small ? 1 : 0}
      {...other}
     >
      {children}
      {cta && (
        <div className="icon" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: CtaIcon   }} />
      )}
    </ButtonWrapper>
    };


    export default Button;
```

Comment: Please post the `Button` component code.

Comment: Edited and shortened my Button component up for clarity

Answer (score 2):

This documentation page might be helpful: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Basically if you use a non-camelcase prop to do styling, it'll get passed through to the DOM node. We're looking into [better alternatives](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/1682) to this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, when I pass **width** or **height** props in to a component they are visible on the html, I think that both words (and maybe others) are actually keywords because with the rest of props this doesn't happen.

*Example*:

```html
<div class="Container-sc-10mm8fh-0 cyDjRF">
  <div class="Line-sc-10mm8fh-1 oPRx"></div>
  <div height="3rem" class="VSpace-sc-18gziyv-1 kkKpPd"></div>
  <div class="Line-sc-10mm8fh-1 oPRx"></div>
  <div height="0.4rem" class="VSpace-sc-18gziyv-1 kkKpPd"></div>
  <div class="Line-sc-10mm8fh-1 oPRx"></div>
</div>
```